# Set JFace wizard dialog message size

Tags: eclipse, dialog, jface, wizard

I implement JFace wizard dialog with single page. The message, that appears while processing my logic, may be a pretty long sentence. But there is only place for about 2 lines of text, which is not enough.

Is there a way to make this place for message between the wizard page and the dialog wizard title higher?

At this point I know that if you set an image for a wizard, this place will be higher, but this is obviously the worst solution I found.
I can not make my wizard wider, because it looks ridiculous after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the image seems to be the only way to control this as the text size calculation is fixed at two lines and can't easily be overridden.

The calculation for this is in the `createTitleArea` private method of `TitleAreaDialog` (which `WizardDialog` extends).